# how to increase performance of data migration from oracle to mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, oracle

I have created an application where I am migrating data(in GBs) from Oracle to mongo. I have used sharding in MongoDB.

How to reduce time consumption for migration and increase the performance rate?

Comment: There is a presentation that might help you https://www.slideshare.net/matkeep/migrating-from-relational-databases-to-mongodb

Comment: Your question is currently too broad to be easily answerable. For example, how is your application inserting data into MongoDB (single inserts, bulk inserts, ...), what specific driver & version are you using, and what version of MongoDB server? Have you profiled your application to get an understanding of where the time is being spent? Are you hitting resources limits of network, disk, CPU, or memory? A more ideal question would focus on one aspect of the migration which can be investigated based on a code example or slow log entries.

Answer (score 1):

Your migration could be slow for a number of reasons. 
It could be because of :

- how the migration code works
- how fast oracle responds to the queries
- how you are pulling the data from oracle(if a stream or something similar is possible)
- directly querying like select *

Also if the two db servers are in the same data center or are seperated. All above are assuming that the two db servers are in the same data center(location or within the same private server area or within same virtual cloud region).

Also depends on the number of indexes which are on oracle (which may impact the rate at which the data is being accessed).

Also if the operations are just reads they should be faster. If you are performing read and update/delete on oracle again the performance could be slower.

This is a very generic question and might have a long list of reasons which are causing the performance issues

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't have a problem at Oracle. Everything at that side is working fast and fine. Problem is writing in MongoDB, which is taking more time

Comment: this might help in that case https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#considerations-before-sharding